# Lightbox plugin not working with PhoneGap images

Tags: jquery, image, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using the PhoneGap Camera plugin and adding an image to my page for each picture selected. The issue I am having is, when I try to implement a Lightbox on those images, I do not get the desired results. If I use the same exact code on an image that was not added via the PhoneGap plugin, everything works perfectly. The only difference in the code between the two images is the src attribute. Below is the code for each:

Normal Image:

```
<a class="photo" href="img/server.png"><img src="server.png" alt="server" /></a>
```

PhoneGap Selected Image:

```
<a class="photo" href="file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.hdl.inspector/cache/1417822999785.jpg">
    <img src="file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.hdl.inspector/cache/1417822999785.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my issue was related to photos being added after page load, rather than anything having to do with the image path. I was initializing 'Magnific Popup' on page load with the following script

```
$('.photo').magnificPopup({
      type: 'image',
      gallery:{
        enabled:true
    },
});
```

Here's the code I used to add the image to my page from the device:

```
function onSuccess(imageURI) {                                        
    var holder = document.getElementById('myImage');
    var image = '<div class="edit-img" ><img class="remove" src="images/remove.png" />&nbsp;<a class="photo" href="' + imageURI + '"><span class="img-name">' + imageURI.lastIndexOf("/") + 1 + '</span>&nbsp;<img class="img-thumb" src="' + imageURI + '" /></a></div>'
    $(holder).after(image);
}
```

The solution was to add the Magnific Popup code inside the function onSuccess(). My final code looks like this:

```
function onSuccess(imageURI) {                                        
    var holder = document.getElementById('myImage');
    var image = '<div class="edit-img" ><img class="remove" src="images/remove.png" />&nbsp;<a class="photo" href="' + imageURI + '"><span class="img-name">' + imageURI.lastIndexOf("/") + 1 + '</span>&nbsp;<img class="img-thumb" src="' + imageURI + '" /></a></div>'
    $(holder).after(image);

    $('.photo').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        gallery:{
          enabled:true
        },
    });
}
```